# Android periodic work manager not working in android 8.1

Tags: android, service, request

I am using a work manager for background service. Work manager works fine in android version 8.0 but not working on android version 8.1. Anyone can help me with this.

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build(); 
PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).setConstraints(constraints).build(); 
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(myWorkRequest);
```

In myWork class

```
 : Log.d("doWork","Work is done");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What so far have you done.

Comment: could you provide some code for us?

Comment: @Ankita I have set periodic work request for 15 minutes when my main activity opens and calls mywork class and for testing currently am log the print in console.

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher  
 Constraints constraints =
                new Constraints.Builder()
                        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                        .build();
        PeriodicWorkRequest myWorkRequest =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .setConstraints(constraints)
                        .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(myWorkRequest);

In myWork class : 
        Log.d("doWork","Work is done");

Comment: should be fine, unless your android 8.1 device might be in power saving mode or something, or it is not connected to the internet as your constraints say. check if you have applied permission in manifest also

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I have added internet permission in the manifest but still, it is not working

Comment: @shilpi have you trying to make sure your "myWorkRequest" is not null?